# how to configure Bitbucket on ubuntu server from scratch?

Tags: linux, git, bitbucket, ubuntu-server, bitbucket-server

I am a front-end developer. I am completely clueless as to how to install/configure Bitbucket on server.

I totally appreciate it if anyone would offer me some guidance. For example, what tools and knowledge do I need to have to configure it successfully.

My plan is to develop locally on my computers, and then git pull the changes on server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Install `git` on remote machine.
- Set up `global configuration for git`. https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration
- Add `SSH` key of remote machine into your bitbucket account.
- `git clone git@git@bitbucket.org:user_name/repo.git`

Comment: thanks. only need to git clone. no need to install Bitbucket Server. ok

Answer (score 0):

First, install git into your system
[Atlass](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/install-git)
Now, Go for git clone repo URL